# ASP.NET Web api 2 secuity

Tags: rest, security, architecture, asp.net-web-api2

We need help in implementing security for Web API's so that they cannot be hack-able or accessible to anyone. I read about the OAuth 2.0 and token based authentication but not sure which one can be best for us.

Can anyone help us to choose correct solution.

Comment: Your question is really too broad, but I suggest you to start by looking at [IdentityServer](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/), which, I believe, is the most complete OAuth/OpenID solution for .NET.

Comment: Thanks for your your suggestion @FedericoDipuma, I will look into the Identity server

Comment: I would suggest  to implement http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2/ series. As I have implemented all series of this article in one of my api project and feel really satisfied with this authentication/authorization mechanism. All the best !